# Configuring CoC -- open suggestion-box with shortcut only

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, plugin-coc

I successfully installed CoC in my Vim to have some code-suggestions/completions while coding in Rust.

It works fine, but I want make the suggestion-box only show up when I press a key-shortcut (E.g Cmd + x)

Comment: Could you split your question? One is for color setup the other is for mapping.

Comment: @MaximKim https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/23328/change-color-of-coc-suggestion-box

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to `coc` readme you can trigger completion manually with:

```
" Use <c-space> to trigger completion.
inoremap <silent><expr> <c-space> coc#refresh()
```

NOTE that not every terminal supports `<c-space>`...

I don't know for sure how to map `cmd` in vim... Probably `D` or something:

```
" Use <CMD-x> to trigger completion.
inoremap <silent><expr> <D-x> coc#refresh()
```

Example with `<C-k>` that should work with most terminals:

```
" Use <C-k> to trigger completion.
inoremap <silent><expr> <C-k> coc#refresh()
```

To turn off autocompletion for coc -- as stated in coc help, you have to add configuration to coc json file:

1. run `:CocConfig`
2. in the opened `coc-settings.json` file add:

```
{
  "suggest.autoTrigger": "none"
}
```

For reference, see `:h CocConfig` and `:h coc-configuration` (search for `autoTrigger`).

Comment: The part to disable autoTrigger works perfectly! However manually opening the pMenu doesn't work yet. The default (c + space) just types a space and 'c' but opens nothing. The remap for D-x doesn't work. Maybe Cmd-key is a problem for the terminal Vim. How would I map Shift + e for example? Maybe that's easier.

Comment: That is because of your terminal doesn't support this mapping. Try to change it to `C-k` for example. Shift + e is not very good as you it would trigger coc-refresh whenever you enter `E` letter (and will not be able to write a simple word with E -- Error, for example)

Comment: Tried adding ```inoremap <silent><expr> <C-k> coc#refresh()``` to the bottom of vimrc, restarted Vim. Pressed Ctrl + k. Did not work.

Comment: what is the output of `:verbose imap <C-k>`?

Comment: and you do press it in insert mode, right? just to dblcheck

Comment: ```i  <C-K>       * coc#refresh()
        Last set from ~/.vimrc line 140
Press ENTER or type command to continue``` is the output. And yes, from insert mode. Thanks

Comment: could u press `Ctrl+Shift+k`?

Comment: and pls do it for the buffer where automatic coc pop-up works. Also coc pop-refresh does nothing if there are no chars before cursor

Comment: Alright mate that works! Thanks! I've used this to bind Shift + Tab for this ```inoremap <silent><expr> <S-Tab> coc#refresh()
```

Answer (score 0):

I added the following lines to my `.vimrc` for this:

```
" Disable Coc suggestions by default, use manual trigger.
autocmd BufEnter * let b:coc_suggest_disable = 1

" Use <c-space> to trigger completion.
if has('nvim')
  inoremap <silent><expr> <c-space> coc#refresh()
else
  inoremap <silent><expr> <c-@> coc#refresh()
endif
```

The first block disables automatic coc-suggestions each time you enter the buffer, and the second configures the `ctrl + spacebar` key combination as a trigger to display suggestions manually.

Of course, you can only disable suggestions for certain file types. For example:

```
autocmd FileType rust let b:coc_suggest_disable = 1
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Instead of `autocmd FileType`, use `ftplugins` (*e.g.*, put `let b:coc_…` in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/rust.vim` (or the neovim equivalent).

Comment: Thanks for your comment! But I'd like to disable suggestions for multiple file types at the same time and don't want to edit a bunch of files. Also, for portability, I prefer to manage all settings from .vimrc only. What are the advantages of your approach, could you explain please?

Comment: Faster load times, for one,  since the filetype mechanism already runs ftplugins using an autocommand. Plus, since your vimrc can live at `~/.vim/vimrc`, you can keep everything in one directory (not the same as a single file, but still fairly portable). And actually you’ll probably find that if/as your settings grow more complicated for filetypes, you’ll appreciate the organization of having dedicated places for that customization.